# Docker image will not launch

Tags: docker

Trying to launch a Docker image but it will not launch the process

The command is as follows:

sudo docker run --security-opt seccomp=unconfined blackarchlinux/blackarch

no error message is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following things

1. see if my container is running or it is created

   $ docker ps or docker ps -a
2. see if my image is pulled ?

   $ docker images
3. if container is created but not running then I could also check the logs

   $ docker logs my-container-name

if you can add in more details, probably would be able to investigate more

Answer (score 0):

You want to start a shell up inside the container and use the tools in there, I assume.

In that case you need to add the `-it` options and tell docker which program/shell you want to run. Something like

```
sudo docker run -it --security-opt seccomp=unconfined blackarchlinux/blackarch /bin/bash
```

Comment: This worked well. I was also wondering if it's possible to launch the desktop environment.

Comment: You might be able to with `X11docker`. I've never played around with it myself though, so I can't help you with that.